# Ubuntu on Macbook pro fails to boot: timer doesn't work through interrupt-remapped io-apic

Tags: boot-failure, mac, macbook-pro, apic, bootcamp

After I was installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro using Wubi in Windows 7 Professional 32-bit and restarted my PC to boot from Ubuntu, I got that message:

```
Kernel panic not syncing  : timer doesn't work through interrupt-remapped io-apic
```

What can I do to start trying this system and fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Boot with noapic in Grub boot parameters. You can do this by pressing "e" when boot prompt is shown :)

I held "c" key down while booting, got 5-item boot menu, chose Start in compatibility mode.